# Heterogeneous Tracing in ZipKin

Tags: profiling, instrumentation, trace, zipkin

I have a heterogeneous(Java, php, python, C#.Net) micro-service system which was written by several teams. All communication happens over HTTP connections.

I objective is to use Zipkin to trace the path of execution and identify the slowest services and start profiling them using (VisualVM, dotTrace). I've heard that Zipkin supports HTTP connectivity for tracing.

How would I go about doing this? Is Zipkin even the right approach? 
I'm looking for direction and some Java examples to get started.
Is there a http format I could use or do I need to use multiple (Wingtips, ZipkinTracerModule,Brave) libraries?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah,you should use different libraries for different languages.
Brave for Java,Zipkin4net for C# and so on.
For more details,you can visit Zipkin official site: [Zipkin Existing instrumentations](https://zipkin.io/pages/existing_instrumentations.html).

Then all you shoud do is following the librarie guide.
Have fun!